# Update multiple rows in table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to learning mysql. I have storedata table having 3 columns

```
 - id     -price     -url
```

and luckyvitamin table having 2 columns

```
-id       -price   -date
```

I want to update the storedata price values using luckyvitamin.

I am using below query.   Please solve my problem.
      Thankyou.

```
update storedata s, luckyvitamin l 
set s.cost = (
    select l1.otcdeal_price 
    from store_data st,luckyvitamin lu  
    where st.id=lu.id
) 
where s.id=l.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE storedata s
INNER JOIN luckyvitamin l
ON s.id = l.id 
SET s.price = l.price
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use an `INNER JOIN` query to achieve this, you don't need any subquery which will make the query itself slower

```
UPDATE storedata s
INNER JOIN luckyvitamin l
ON s.id = l.id
SET s.cost = l.otcdeal_pric
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
update storedata s inner join luckyvitamin l on s.id=l.id
set s.cost= l.otcdeal_price;
```